# Creating "background running" children with fork() and kill each of them with signals

Tags: c, linux, fork, children, zombie-process

I need to create **n** children from the same parent, and have them running while the parent asks infinitely for a signal to send to some child. I made the parent create those **n** children, but they finished executing, so I made them enter a while(1) loop. The problem is, when I try to kill any child, it  becomes a zombie process instead of actually terminating its execution. I'm guessing that's because the parent is still waiting for the children to terminate execution and they don't send the exit status. So... First of all, do I really need to make the children enter an infinite while loop to make them be running while the parent is asking for the signals? If I do, how do I avoid this "never terminating execution" problem? I need to find a way for the children to exit that while loop and send the actual "finished execution" signal since I think I can't use `wait()` because the children never actually finish running, they are just terminated by the parent.

Thanks.
PS: Running in Linux. This is my code

```
int main(){
    int i;
    pid_t parent = getpid();
    pid_t pid[4];
    printf("parent with pid %d\n", parent);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        pid[i] = fork();
        if(pid[i] < 0){
            perror("Error in fork.");
            exit(1);
        } else if(pid[i] == 0 && getppid() == padre) {
            printf("Number: %d   pid %d, parent: %d\n", i, getpid(), getppid());
            while(1);
        }
    }

    if(getpid() == padre){
        while(1){
            printf("Enter pid and signal:\n");
            int x, y;
            scanf("%d", &x); // pid
            scanf("%d", &y); // signal
            printf("you did: kill(%d, %d)\n", x, y);
            kill(x, y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Final code with answer implemented: https://github.com/sebasura/sistope

Comment: Read about the [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) system call, and it siblings.

Comment: A `waitpid()` call after the kill would be a good start.

Comment: Rather than `while(1);`, you might prefer `pause()`.

Comment: You allocate `pid_t pids[4]` and promptly create 5 children.  Happiness is not assured.

Comment: I fixed that, thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is, when I try to kill any child, it becomes a zombie process instead of actually terminating its execution.

Well, yes and no.  Becoming a zombie is normally what happens when a process terminates, until that process is collected by its parent.  A zombie takes up a bit of space in the process table, but it is not *running*, and therefore consumes no CPU.

> I'm guessing that's because the parent is still waiting for the children to terminate execution and they don't send the exit status.

No, it's because `kill()` just sends a signal.  You need to use one of the `wait()` functions -- perhaps `waitpid()` -- to actually collect the terminated child.

> So... First of all, do I really need to make the children enter an infinite while loop to make them be running while the parent is asking for the signals?

No.  The child can use `sigwait()` or one of its variants to wait for a signal from a designated set, or `pause()` to suspend execution pending receipt of any signal that terminates the process or triggers a signal handler function.  Note, however, that there are some signals that by default do neither of those, so `sigwait()` is probably the better alternative.

> If I do, how do I avoid this "never terminating execution" problem?

The child must terminate as a result of receiving the signal.  That's already happening for you, because the children are becoming zombies.  With your present code it may depend on which signal you send, however, for there are some whose default handling does not terminate the process.

Comment: Alright so what I need to do is: Get rid of that while(1) loop in the children and replace that by either pause() or sigwait(), and then collect the children with waitpid() after the kill(), right? I have no idea how to use sigwait() and I'm kinda lost with waitpid(). The only signals I need to use are SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2 and SIGTERM, so I think pause() would be fine. I tried collecting the children with waitpid(x, &state, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED); but it does nothing about the zombie children. I don't really know how to implement those changes 'cause I don't fully understand the functions v_v.

Comment: @Sebasuraa, yes, except definitely do not use `WNOHANG`, and probably do not use `WUNTRACED`.  The former in particular will introduce a race condition -- the child will be collected if it happens to terminate before the parent's `waitpid()` call, but otherwise not.  The parent was nothing better to do than to wait, if necessary, for the child to terminate, so that's what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I did it.
I used `pause()` instead of `while(1)`.

And after the kill, I used this:

```
int state;
waitpid(pid, &state, 0);
```

This is part of a homework so I will upload the code after the due date so they don't penalize me for sharing it or something.

Thanks again.
EDIT:
Here is the final code https://github.com/sebasura/sistope